# How to translate a script using "case_when" for a script using "dt_case_when"

Tags: r, dplyr

I am checking whether I can substitute the case_when function that I use in some of my scripts for the dt_case_when function which seems to be faster. When I check the following code, it seems that the TRUE statement does nothing. Has somebody found a potential solution? Thanks!

I am copying the script with the case_when function to see the expected result.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3","ID_4"),
                 Status = c(NA_character_, "Alive", "Alive", NA_character_))

df %>%
  mutate(
    Value = case_when(
      Status == "Alive" ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0      
    )
  )

df %>%
  mutate(
    Value = dt_case_when(
      Status == "Alive" ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0      
    )
  )
```

TRUE is not working in the dt_case_when as it does in case_when

Comment: Is this the function from the `tidyfast` package? Or where does the `dt_case_when` function come from?

Comment: Yes, this is from tidyfast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises because of `NA` values in `Status`. The `TRUE ~ 0` part of `dplyr::case_when()` is a default value that is assigned if no other conditions are met. `Status == "Alive"` does not evaluate to `TRUE` for `NA`,  so the result is `0` for `NA` values.

Conversely, as the `tidyfast::dt_case_when()` [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyfast/versions/0.2.1/topics/dt_case_when) state, the function:

> Does what `dplyr::case_when()` does, with the same syntax, but with `data.table::fifelse()` under the hood.

This means essentially you are doing this:

```r
df  |>
    mutate(
        Value = data.table::fifelse(Status == "Alive", 1, 0)
    )
#   Name Status Value
# 1 ID_1   <NA>    NA
# 2 ID_2  Alive     1
# 3 ID_3  Alive     1
# 4 ID_4   <NA>    NA
```

As you can see, unlike `case_when()`, [`data.table::fifelse()`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fifelse.html) returns `NA` if the value being tested is `NA`. This is the same behaviour as [`base::ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) and [`dplyr::if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html).

If you need a faster alternative to `dplyr::case_when()`, you can just use [`data.table::fcase()`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fcase.html), which has the same behaviour with `NA` values as `case_when()`.

This can be done using `dplyr` syntax:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    Value = data.table::fcase(
        Status == "Alive", 1,
        default = 0
    )
  )
#   Name Status Value
# 1 ID_1   <NA>     0
# 2 ID_2  Alive     1
# 3 ID_3  Alive     1
# 4 ID_4   <NA>     0
```

Or alternatively just use `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Value := fcase(
    Status == "Alive", 1,
    default = 0
)]
# Same result
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't aware about if_else returning NAs when the value being evaluated was NA.